# Rearranging the contents of a file in place

Tags: c, archive, in-place

I'm trying to optimize an archive format which stores data in nodes. As time goes on the container becomes messy (small unusable "free" space nodes accumulate etc). What I'm doing is similar to defragmenting. I already have a list of all the data locations, and a representation of where I would like the data to be in its final state, but I'm struggling on the task of moving the actual data from its current configuration into the optimal configuration. The elements are not the same size nor multiples of any smallest block (unless you count bytes). Is there some obvious method I am overlooking? I'm not even sure what this problem is called to search for algorithms, the closest I've gotten is in-place sorting.

So far I have tried swapping blocks of data but I need to keep track of node fragments, and it's become way too messy to be feasible.

I don't want to resort to writing a temporary copy and then replacing, since the files are very large.

Comment: Since the archive is on the file system, doesn't the file system automatically set word boundaries on that data automatically?  What I'm asking is, aren't those small unusable "free" space nodes there because of the boundaries caused by the file system, and not actually the archiver?

Comment: no, the format isn't quite that low level, its literally a header and then binary data, and free space is marked by a length and the tag FREE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding performance, copying the data to a new file will most likely be the best choice.

If available disk space is an issue, you have a fun time ahead of you, because this will require some exquisite hacking skills to get fast. I think, the best can do is to allocate a large slap of buffer memory and maintain a list of holes in the file whose data resides within this buffer. Then you start by filling this buffer with everything that's out of place, starting at the beginning of the file. Once the buffer is full, you can copy data from anywhere into the hole and keep pushing data into the buffer at the end of the hole you are filling. Whenever you run out of buffer space, you will need to jump the biggest hole available and move the data that belongs there. As I said, this won't be easy, but it might be fun...

Comment: that sounds interesting. As long as the buffer doesn't fill with data that has nowhere to be moved yet. I guess I could replace the buffer with a temporary file if needed, it should never approach the size of the full archive

Comment: You can also append the buffer contents to the end of the file as you "compact" the free space. Once the original EOF is reached, you can truncate the remaining free space or leave for future use.

Comment: I doubt that it would be worth the time to write the buffer out to a file because that would mean more disc accesses. With the algorithm I outlined above, you only need to read and write each byte once. If you use a temporary file, this increases to two times. It might look just as fast at first because modern systems will silently buffer your temporary file, but it is additional operations at any rate. Of course, you can always try to prove me wrong... :-)

Comment: ah yeah, that's true. I'm going to try allocating a seperate block of memory for each item that is being displaced, to avoid mallocing one huge buffer all at once. That and I don't want to make a decision as to how big the large buffer should be =P. Then I can free the blocks as items are moved out of the "buffer"

Comment: I see two dangers with the approach of dynamically allocating the memory, even though I normally advocate for malloc: 1) I fear heap fragmentation. On average, your application will use roughly twice as much memory as you think you are using, but a bad sequence of malloced sizes can make your heap grow indefinitely, pushing your system into an out of memory situation. 2) The OOM-killer. I don't know about Windows, but Linux has the habit to just run amok and shoot down processes when it runs out of memory. If that happens to your program, the result will be a corrupted file.

Comment: It's on windows. I did consider that, and I kept track of how much memory I had checked out for buffer space and I'd make it abort if it went past my arbitrary limit of 500 MB, which it never hit (overall it used much less memory than I expected it to). So I have that done, although I have missed something else because a checking utility complains about incorrect hashes on some files, which is strange considering I copied them exactly, and the hashes are on the content of the data, which hasn't changed. Currently attempting to debug that